# Effective way to find checksum in perl without memory leakage

Tags: perl

In my program I need to look for checksum for many files. The checksum calculation is within the find command.

```
find(sub {
        my $file = $File::Find::name;
        return if ! length($file);
open (FILE, "$file");
my $chksum = md5_base64(<FILE>);
close FILE;
}, "/home/nijin");
```

The above code works perfectly. But if there is a file with a large size for example 6GB in the path /home/nijin, it will load 6 GB into RAM memory and the process takes 6 GB RAM continuously until the process is completed. Please note that this is a backup process and it will take more than 12 hours for the process to complete. So I will lose 6GB until the process is completed. The worst case is the process gets hangs due to large memory usage. As an option I have tried to use  `File::Map` . the code is pasted below.

```
find(sub {
            my $file = $File::Find::name;
            return if ! length($file);
   map_file my $map, "$filename", '<';
    my $chksum = md5_base64($map);
    }, "/home/nijin");
```

The above code also works but I am getting segmentation fault error while using the above code. I have also tried with `Sys::Mmap` but having the same issue as the first one. Is there any other option to try?

Comment: If you want the memory back, run the expensive calculation in a child process.

Comment: @choroba, running child process may not help my situation. Is there any other option?

Comment: What do you mean by "may not help"?

Comment: If the checksums are for your application's private use only, have you considered hashing, say, 1GiB chunks and storing an array of checksums rather than hashing the whole file at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to read the whole file into memory at once.

You can explicitly process it in 64k chunks by the following:

```
my $chksum = do {
    open my $fh, '<:raw', $file;
    my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new;
    local $/ = \65536; # Read 64k at once
    while (<$fh>) {
        $md5->add($_);
    }
    $md5->hexdigest;
};
# Do whatever you were going to do with it here
```

You can also just pass the filehandle directly, although that does not guarantee how it will process it:

```
my $chksum = do {
    open my $fh, '<:raw', $file;
    Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh)->hexdigest
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd run the expensive calculation in a child process. This keeps the parent process at decent memory consumption. The child can eat lots of memory for large files, but once the MD5 is returned, the memory is returned to the OS:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use File::Find;
use Digest::MD5 qw{ md5_base64 };

my %md5;

find(sub {
         my $name = $File::Find::name;
         return unless -f;

         my $child_pid = open(my $CMD, '-|') // die "Can't fork: $!";

         if ($child_pid) {                                  # Parent
             $md5{$name} = <$CMD>;
             wait;

         } else {                                           # Child
             open my $IN, '<', $_ or die "$name: $!";
             print md5_base64(<$IN>);
             exit;
         }

     }, shift);

print Dumper \%md5;
```